# Cheap alternative to 3M IC clips?

Tags: integrated-circuit, logic-analyzer, dip, test-equipment

I'd like to connect my logic analyzer to the address and data lines of a 6264 parallel SRAM chip on a PCB I'm working on. It's a 28-pin, .600 mil DIP package.

I have a 3M test clip for a .300 mil DIP28, but it won't fit, and new ones are very expensive. I don't have any minigrabbers either.

Does anyone have an interesting hack for piggybacking wires to a DIP in-circuit? I was thinking about soldering some wires to a DIP socket, or 2 rows of header pins on a piece of perfboard, then wedging it on top of the chip. Not sure either will have the strength to stay in place and maintain all connections though.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's a DIP you could solder 1 x 14 headers directly to the pins on the bottom of the board, or on the top to the sides of the chip pins.

Cut the headers apart when it's time to take them off, to allow them to be removed more easily, and then clean up with some solder wick.

If it's necessary to keep the PCB relatively virgin and access from the top, I'd be tempted to just solder wire-wrap or enameled AWG30 wires from the pins on the bottom to a couple headers in perf board.

You could do something with pogo pins too (the cup type that contact the tips of the DIP pins directly) - solder the pogo pins into perf board or another sacrificial board .. but that would probably cost more than buying a clip.

[image]